# Regarding I/O operations for OtherOperationCount

Tags: .net, winapi

In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684125(v=vs.85).aspx
it mentions

> OtherOperationCount The number of I/O operations performed, other than
>   read and write operations.

But what are examples of these operations?

Comment: for example device io control file (`ZwDeviceIoControlFile`) or fs control file (`ZwFsControlFile`) both this api called from `DeviceIoControl`

Answer (score 2):

you need have *Windows Research Kernel 1.2* for understand this. look for [`IopSynchronousServiceTail`](https://github.com/lmr3796/WRK-1.2/blob/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c#L7417) in `base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c`. at very begin of this function exist [`next code`](https://github.com/lmr3796/WRK-1.2/blob/master/base/ntos/io/iomgr/internal.c#L7471):

```
//
// Update the operation count statistic for the current process.
//

switch( TransferType ) {

case ReadTransfer:
    IopUpdateReadOperationCount();
    break;

case WriteTransfer:
    IopUpdateWriteOperationCount();
    break;

case OtherTransfer:
    IopUpdateOtherOperationCount();
    break;
}
```

so search for string `OtherTransfer` inside `base/ntos/io/iomgr` folder - and you found huge count of api which use it:

```
NtDeviceIoControlFile
NtFsControlFile
NtQueryDirectoryFil
NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile
NtLockFile
NtUnlockFile 
NtFlushBuffersFile 
NtQueryEaFile
NtSetEaFile 
NtSetVolumeInformationFile 
NtQueryVolumeInformationFile
NtQueryQuotaInformationFile  
NtSetQuotaInformationFile
...
```